# Firebase Query to check if a value exists before adding, if true, donot proceed to add,if false add

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi a newbie in android dev, pls in this pick a username activity, i want to app to check if username exists in firebase database, if true, show dialog and donot add value to database, if false add. so far if its true, it proceeds to add to firebase database.. Anything i did wrong?

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_check);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


        pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
        FirebaseUser curr_user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        String uid = null;
        if (curr_user != null) {
            uid = curr_user.getUid();

            mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(uid);


            cUser = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.cUserr);
            cBut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cCon);

            TextView backArrow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.home);
            backArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent mainintent = new Intent(CheckUsername.this, MainActivity.class);
                    mainintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(mainintent);
                    finish();
                }
            });
```

this where i called the check if username exists method

```
            cBut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onClick: attempting to save changes.");
                    checkIfUsernameExists("");


                }
            });
        }
    }


    private void saveProfileSettings() {


        final String username = cUser.getEditText().toString();


        //case1: if the user made a change to their username
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(username)) {
            cUser.setError("Empty Field");
        } else {
//            checkIfUsernameExists(username);
        }
    }
```

here i check to see if it exists, if true call alert dialog but it seems not todo that, all it does is create thhe value into database if it exists or not

```
    private void checkIfUsernameExists(final String username) {
        Log.d(TAG, "checkIfUsernameExists: Checking if  " + username + " already exists.");

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Query query = reference
                .child(getString(R.string.dbname_users))
                .orderByChild(getString(R.string.field_username))
                .equalTo(username);
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    //add the username
                    updateUsername(username);
                    Toast.makeText(CheckUsername.this, "saved username.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                for (DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    if (!singleSnapshot.exists()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "checkIfUsernameExists: FOUND A MATCH: " + singleSnapshot.getValue(Users.class).getName());
                        request_code();
                        Toast.makeText(CheckUsername.this, "That username already exists.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }



                @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
```

this is the alert dialog method to be called inside the check username method, but it seems not to work.

```
    public void request_code(){

        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle("Pls Enter a Different Username");

        alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            }
        });

        alert.show();
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you make USERNAME is Unique  so I guess Just

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query query = reference
            .child(getString(R.string.dbname_users))
            .orderByChild(getString(R.string.field_username))
            .equalTo(username);
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                //add the username
                updateUsername(username);
                Toast.makeText(CheckUsername.this, "saved username.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        else
           {
                                  request_code();

             }


            }
        }
```

Comment: It still adds the username even if it exists. I dunno what to do, can i do it on firebase database rules??